# Parsing a list of 0 or more idents followed by ident

Tags: scala, parsing, parser-combinators

I want to parse a part of my DSL formed like this:

```
configSignal: sticky Config
```

Semantically this is:

```
argument_name: 0_or_more_modifiers argument_type
```

I tried implementing the following parser:

```
def parser = ident ~ ":" ~ rep(ident) ~ ident ^^ {
    case name ~ ":" ~ modifiers ~ returnType => Arg(name, returnType, modifiers)
}
```

Thing is, the `rep(ident)` part is applied until there are no more tokens and the parser fails, because the last `~ ident` doesn't match. How should I do this properly?

**Edit**

In the meantime I realized, that the modifiers will be reserved words (keywords), so now I have:

```
def parser = ident ~ ":" ~ rep(modifier) ~ ident ^^ {
    case name ~ ":" ~ modifiers ~ returnType => Arg(name, returnType, modifiers)
}

def modifier = "sticky" | "control" | "count"
```

Nevertheless, I'm curious if it would be possible to write a parser if the modifiers weren't defined up front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"0 or more idents followed by ident" is equivalent to "1 or more idents", so just use [`rep1`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/index.html#scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers)

Its docs:

```
def rep1[T](p: ⇒ Parser[T]): Parser[List[T]]
```

> A parser generator for non-empty repetitions.
>
> rep1(p) repeatedly uses p to parse the input until p fails -- p must succeed at least once (the result is a List of the consecutive results of p)
>
> **p** a Parser that is to be applied successively to the input
>   **returns** A parser that returns a list of results produced by repeatedly applying p to the input (and that only succeeds if p matches at least once).

---

*edit in response to OP's comment:*

I don't think there's a built-in way to do what you described, but it would still be relatively easy to map to your custom data types by using regular List methods:

```
def parser = ident ~ ":" ~ rep1(ident) ^^ {
  case name ~ ":" ~ idents => Arg(name, idents.last, idents.dropRight(1))
}
```

In this particular case, you wouldn't have to worry about `idents` being `Nil`, since the `rep1` parser only succeeds with a non-empty list.

Comment: Perhaps I should have stated this more clearly. I want the parsing result to be easy to map to my data structures. Therefore I want this separation between modifiers and argument_type. See my updated question

Comment: After pondering about it with a friend of mine, we also came to conclusion that it's rather impossible to implement it the way I'd like to. The parser would have to read two tokens in advance and I think it's not the case with the parser combinators library.